# Difference between two datagrid column values and display the result in a new column

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have a datagrid that displays a table from a database as follows :

[image]

I have to added a new column called "`Difference`" which should display the difference between the `Scores1` column value & the `Scores2` column value.

(P.S : No negative values from the difference)

How to achieve this in WPF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with WPF but, Is `wpfdatagrid` has `TemplateField` or any other related structure ?

If so, you can done it like this;

```
<ItemTemplate>
   <asp:Literal 
       ID="Literal4" 
       runat="server" 
       Text='<%# (Decimal.Parse(Eval("Score1")) - Decimal.Parse(Eval("Score2")) %>'>
    </asp:Literal>
  </ItemTemplate>
```

**NOTE**: This code for `Gridview`. It doesn't work on `wpfdatagrid` but it can gives you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Do a query / view / stored proc for it

e.g. something like

Select Scores1, Scores2, 
case When Scores1 - Scores2 > 0 then Scores1 - scores2 else 0 end as Difference
From SomeTable

You could add a column to data grid and fill it, but it's a lot more messing about.

Comment: You mean that I can achieve this with select statement from code behind ??

Comment: Yes of course you can. A few adjustments, and you could select only those that are different, or those that are different by > x.